# Sampling Hidden Markov Model

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I am studying hidden Markov models, but I have some doubts about the inference phase. If I have any observations and I want to know the three parameters that characterize the model, can I use one of the MCMC techniques directly on the observations or do I have to first use the Viterbi algorithm or the forward-backward algorithm on the observations and then use one of MCMC techniques to know the three parameters?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is not clear to me. But if you want to sample from HMM, [forward sampling](http://pgm.stanford.edu/Algs/page-489.pdf) can be used. Assuming $X$ are hidden states and $Y$ is observations, and we want to sample $N$ observations.

[image]

The steps are:

- Sample from $X_1$
- Based on the sample we got of $X_1$ and $P(Y_1|X_1)$, sample $Y_1$
- Based on the sample we got of $X_1$ and $P(Y_2|X_1)$, sample $X_2$
- $\cdots$

Comment: Hi, I apologize for the lack of clarity of the question. But the hidden states I can sample them through one of the mcmc techniques or I must necessarily use the forward sampling?

Comment: why MCMC? that is the part I do not understand.

Comment: I read a pdf file where it is written: Markov Chain Monte Carlo  methods observe a series of observations, and iteratively costruct a markov chain such that it's equilibrium distribution. This is the pdf file site:https://www.isi.edu/~galstyan/courses/Presentations/zachlevine_presentation.pdf

Comment: @G.Carlà i think you confused with HMM learning and HMM sampling/inference.

Comment: You could kindly clarify the situation. Thanks in advance

Comment: @G.Carlà HMM learning is trying to estimate the parameters of the model from data. HMM inference/sampling is generate simulated data from a given model.

Comment: So, I need to use learning to know the data parameters. Correct? If you could point me to a book or more books about learning techniques. Thanks in advance

Comment: @G.Carlà Here is the best resource I know for HMM from experience when starting from scratch. http://melodi.ee.washington.edu/people/bilmes/mypapers/em.pdf
Be aware that there are also many libraries in many languages that have these approaches implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but I think the answer is actually misleading. You don't want to do 'forward sampling' here (I think the reference linked was from the Kohler PGM book which states that forward sampling like this doesn't apply to directed graphical models), and the procedure to sample in an unbiased way is actually:

- Take the last forward probability and sample a hidden state from that.
- Sample from the previous hidden state conditional on the last hidden state being known (i.e. multiply the forward probabilities at
  position L - 1 by the transition matrix to the known hidden state
- Continue back down the chain until you reach the first index

I hope this procedure is helpful / correct, as I don't often see it outlined in books